# unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe

Tags: jpype, jaydebeapi

Has anyone encountered such a problem before? Every time I run  `jaydebeapi.connnect(......)`, python stops working and I encounter this error..
`unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe`

I tried `jpype.startJVM('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_161\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll')`. I get the same error.

Here is the connection details I used.

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.cac.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:cac:CACSAMP:tcp/XX.x.x.xx/xxxx'
                          , {'user': 'XXXX', 'password': 'XXXXX'},
                          "C:\\IBM2\\SDPShared\\plugins\\com.ibm.datatools.dbdefinition.db2.cac."
                          "classic_11.3.0.201506231108\\driver\\cacjdbc21.jar")
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your python version is 64 bit and the JVM is 32 bit.  Mixing the size is not allowed.